# Markup language for Java that is XSS safe

Tags: java, markdown, wiki, xss

I'm writing a java webapp and I'd like to let my users enter text containing markup that is [XSS / Cross-Site-Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) safe. I'd like to save the user generated markup to a database and display it as HTML.

I am aware of [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) but this allows raw HTML to be entered which is not XSS safe.

Are there any wiki-like / markdown-like interpreters in java that are XSS safe? I'd also like to hear of any javascript / wysiwig editors that might help here.

Alternatively, are there any XSS filters in java that can sanitize HTML so that it is XSS safe.

Answer (score 3):

I use Markdown (actually Pegdown) together with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) which works well.

Jsoup...

> - cleans user-submitted content against a safe white-list, to prevent XSS attacks.
> - output tidy HTML

Comment: You can also use [Pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown) together with the `SUPPRESS_ALL_HTML` extension: HTML blocks and inline HTML tags will get read but not be contained in the input. Without HTML tags Markdown is safe.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at JSoup, which allows you to specify a Whitelist: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use a WYSIWIG editor (CKEditor or TinyMCE) + jsoup to sanitize.

Comment: @uklance you're welcome we use CKEditor + JSoup combo and it works great. I have also used TinyMCE, both are good. Good luck!